# How to parse html page and by pass the symbol

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an HTML page. Whenever I am submitting this page through ajax and trying to store it on the server, it deny storing the HTML page. I think this something related with HTML parsing. So is there any way to parse the HTML file?

I mean to bypass the closing symbol (/) and double quotes ("") and all these kinds of stuff. I can successfully submit the text but can not submit the HTML Code.

Comment: "_this page_". What page?

Comment: I have the custom content, thats was fetched from a textarea and stored on a variable

Comment: I think you can add this code addslashes($_POST['textarea'])  in your php

Comment: Is it possible to do it with Javascript ?

Comment: This sounds llike a problem at the server-side, JS can't store anything to your server, and it's hard to imagine a browser would refuse to submit some HTML. We've no clue of your code, so please show your code which receives the submission and tries to store the HTML.

Comment: @user3030404 You've been given great feedback by Teemu that I will reiterate.  Please edit your answer.  1- include the code (html, javascript, php, etc.) that is not working; 2- include the steps you are taking to reproduce the problem; and 3- include any error messages you may be receiving.  if you're not receiving error messages, please post the network request and response from your browser's development mode: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/tools-for-pwa-developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store in the base64 format in database

example:

```
$content = '<html>
<head>
  <script>--JavaScript libraries--</script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <style>--Styling--</style>
</body>
</html>';
```

to encode in base64 format

```
$encoded = base64_encode($content);
```

to decode from base64 format

```
$Decoded = base64_decode($content);
```